# Minimal executable size now 10x larger after linking than 2 years ago, for tiny programs?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, linker, ld

For a university course, I like to compare code-sizes of functionally similar programs if written and compiled using gcc/clang versus assembly. In the process of re-evaluating how to further shrink the size of some executables, I couldn't trust my eyes when the very same assembly code I assembled/linked 2 years ago now has grown >10x in size after building it again (which true for multiple programs, not only helloworld):

```
$ make
as -32 -o helloworld-asm-2020.o helloworld-asm-2020.s
ld -melf_i386 -o helloworld-asm-2020 helloworld-asm-2020.o

$ ls -l
-rwxr-xr-x 1 xxx users  708 Jul 18  2018 helloworld-asm-2018*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 xxx users 8704 Nov 25 15:00 helloworld-asm-2020*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 xxx users 4724 Nov 25 15:00 helloworld-asm-2020-n*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 xxx users 4228 Nov 25 15:00 helloworld-asm-2020-n-sstripped*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 xxx users  604 Nov 25 15:00 helloworld-asm-2020.o*
-rw-r--r-- 1 xxx users  498 Nov 25 14:44 helloworld-asm-2020.s
```

The assembly code is:

```
.code32
.section .data
msg: .ascii "Hello, world!\n"
         len = . - msg

.section .text
.globl _start

_start:
        movl $len, %edx   # EDX = message length
        movl $msg, %ecx   # ECX = address of message
        movl $1, %ebx     # EBX = file descriptor (1 = stdout)
        movl $4, %eax     # EAX = syscall number (4 = write)
        int $0x80         # call kernel by interrupt

        # and exit
        movl $0, %ebx     # return code is zero
        movl $1, %eax     # exit syscall number (1 = exit)
        int $0x80         # call kernel again
```

The same hello world program, compiled using GNU `as` and GNU `ld` (always using 32-bit assembly) was 708 bytes then, and has grown to 8.5K now. Even when telling the linker to turn off page alignment (`ld -n`), it still has almost 4.2K. `strip`ping/`sstrip`ping doesn't pay off either.

`readelf` tells me that the start of section headers is much later in the code (byte 468 vs 8464), but I have no idea why. It's running on the same arch system as in 2018, the Makefile is the same and I'm not linking against any libraries (especially not libc). I guess something regarding `ld` has changed due to the fact that the object file is still quite small, but what and why?

Disclaimer: I'm building 32-bit executables on an x86-64 machine.

Edit: I'm using GNU binutils (as & ld) version 2.35.1 Here is a base64-encoded archive which includes the source and both executables (small old one, large new one) :

```
cat << EOF | base64 -d | tar xj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EOF
```

**Update:**
When using `ld.gold` instead of `ld.bfd` (to which `/usr/bin/ld` is symlinked to by default), the executable size becomes as small as expected:

```
$ cat Makefile 
TARGET=helloworld
all:
    as -32 -o ${TARGET}-asm.o ${TARGET}-asm.s
    ld.bfd -melf_i386 -o ${TARGET}-asm-bfd ${TARGET}-asm.o
    ld.gold -melf_i386 -o ${TARGET}-asm-gold ${TARGET}-asm.o
    rm ${TARGET}-asm.o

$ make -q
$ ls -l
total 68
-rw-r--r-- 1 eso eso   200 Dec  1 13:57 Makefile
-rwxrwxr-x 1 eso eso  8700 Dec  1 13:57 helloworld-asm-bfd
-rwxrwxr-x 1 eso eso   732 Dec  1 13:57 helloworld-asm-gold
-rw-r--r-- 1 eso eso   498 Dec  1 13:44 helloworld-asm.s
```

Maybe I just used `gold` previously without being aware.

Comment: Given that the files are quite small, could you compress and then base64 encode them?  Then you could put them directly into the question, making it self-contained (questions depending on external resources are frowned upon on this site).  Also mention the exact assembler and linker versions if possible.

Comment: Depends on your linker version, yes. It's 652 bytes for me with debian ld 2.28. Nowadays `.data` and `.text` should not overlap due to no-execute, so that gives you some padding. Since your string is a constant you can put it into `.text` and that should give you a small size again.

Comment: That padding of course does not result in 10 times growth in general, it's just shocking for such small programs.

Comment: It's not 10x in general, it's page-alignment of a couple sections as Jester says, per changes to `ld`'s default linker script for security reasons.  So it has a worst-case upper bound of about 2x 4k pages, and tiny executables are close to that worst case.  `gcc -Wl,--nmagic` will turn off page-alignment of sections if you want that for some reason.  (see the [`ld(1)` man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ld.1.html))

Comment: @PeterCordes OP mentioned using `-n` and that it didn't help quite as much as he'd hoped it would.

Comment: The question really is why were you expecting the same result with newer/different tools?

Comment: I had a chance to look at this. What if you add the option `-no-pie` to the link options? I noticed the reason it is larger is because there is a global offset table in one which suggests by default one of the environments decided to assume a position independent executable and the other not.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: (update: nevermind, they aren't linking libc). I think `ld.bfd` defaults to `-no-pie`, but it will convert library calls like `call printf` to `call printf@plt` for you, and generate a PLT entry and a corresponding GOT entry.  This being 32-bit code, perhaps `ld.gold` just leaves a runtime fixup for the actual libc `printf` symbol?  I didn't look at the binary, and the OP hasn't provided source.  I was assuming they'd use a `write` system call, not printf.  Oh, but since they don't use `-lc`, that seems unlikely.

Comment: @PeterCordes : if you decode the base64 in the question and unbzip2 and untar the result you can see the source code and he has versions of both ELF executables. An objdump makes the issue pretty apparent. The makefile is in the question.

Answer (score 14):

It's not 10x in general, it's page-alignment of a couple sections as Jester says, per changes to `ld`'s default linker script for security reasons:

- First change: Making sure data from `.data` isn't present in any of the mapping of `.text`, so none of that static data is available for ROP / Spectre gadgets in an executable page.  (In older `ld`, that meant the program-headers mapped the same disk-block twice, also into a RW-without-exec segment for the actual .data section.  The executable mapping was still read-only.)
- More recent change: Separate `.rodata` from `.text` into separate segments, again so static data isn't mapped into an executable page.  Previously, `const char code[]= {...}` could be cast to a function pointer and called, without needing mprotect or `gcc -z execstack` or other tricks, if you wanted to [test shellcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9960721/how-to-get-c-code-to-execute-hex-machine-code/55893781#55893781) that way.  (A separate Linux kernel change made `-z execstack` only apply to the actual stack, not READ_IMPLIES_EXEC.)
- See [Why an ELF executable could have 4 LOAD segments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57761007/why-an-elf-executable-could-have-4-load-segments/57841768#57841768) for this history, including the strange fact that `.rodata` is in a separate segment from the read-only mapping for access to the ELF metadata.

That extra space is just `00` padding and will compress well in a `.tar.gz` or whatever.

**So it has a worst-case upper bound of about 2x 4k extra pages of padding, and tiny executables are close to that worst case.**

`gcc -Wl,--nmagic` will turn off page-alignment of sections if you want that for some reason.  (see the [`ld(1)` man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ld.1.html))  I don't know why that doesn't pack everything down to the old size.  Perhaps checking the default linker script would shed some light, but it's pretty long. Run `ld --verbose` to see it.

`strip`ping won't help for padding that's part of a section; I think it can only remove whole sections.

**`ld -z noseparate-code`** uses the old layout, only 2 total segments to cover the `.text` and `.rodata` sections, and the `.data` and `.bss` sections.  (And the ELF metadata that dynamic linking wants access to.)

---

#### Related:

###### Linking with `gcc` instead of `ld`

This question is about `ld`, but note that if you're using `gcc -nostdlib`, that used to also default to making a static executable.  But modern Linux distros config GCC with `-pie` as the default, and GCC [won't make a static-pie by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60570279/what-is-a-reasonable-minimum-number-of-assembly-instructions-for-a-small-c-progr) even if there aren't any shared libraries being linked.  Unlike with `-no-pie` mode where it will simply make a static executable in that case.   (A [static-pie](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61553723) still needs startup code to apply relocations for any absolute addresses.)

So the equivalent of `ld` directly is `gcc -nostdlib -static` (which implies `-no-pie`).  Or `gcc -nostdlib -no-pie` should let it default to `-static` when there are no shared libs being linked.  You can combine this with `-Wl,--nmagic` and/or `-Wl,-z -Wl,noseparate-code`.

Also:

- [A Whirlwind Tutorial on Creating Really Teensy ELF Executables for Linux](https://www.muppetlabs.com/%7Ebreadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html) - eventually making a 45 byte executable, with the machine code for an `_exit` syscall stuffed into the ELF program header itself.
- FASM can make quite small executables, using its mode where it outputs a static executable (not object file) directly with no ELF section metadata, just program headers.  (It's a pain to debug with GDB or disassemble with objdump; most tools assume there will be section headers, even though they're not needed to run static executables.)
- [What is a reasonable minimum number of assembly instructions for a small C program including setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60570279/what-is-a-reasonable-minimum-number-of-assembly-instructions-for-a-small-c-progr)
- [What's the difference between "statically linked" and "not a dynamic executable" from Linux ldd?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61553723/whats-the-difference-between-statically-linked-and-not-a-dynamic-executable) (static vs. static-pie vs. (dynamic) PIE that happens to have no shared libraries.)

Comment: Thanks Peter, I've bindiff'ed the binaries and you're right that its largely 0x00 padding. I also tried linking on an Ubuntu 20.04 using ld 2.34 with similar results - I'll still wait with marking it solved, in case any concrete solution comes along. Unfortunately, -n/--nmagic doesn't fully shrink it back.

Comment: I had never bothered to investigate this until a little while ago. One big difference is that the executables that the OP encoded into the archive in the question show that one of the versions (ld.bfd) generated an extra section with a global offset table in it. I suggested in a comment that they attempt to link with with the `-no-pie` option and see what happens.

Comment: Also related: [GCC is generating binaries filled with zeroes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59026218), and another example case (with C and asm linked together): [gcc "hello world" 10x larger binary than expected](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67153734)