# Does a const char* literal string persistently exist as long as the process alive?

Tags: c++, constants, constexpr, lifetime, null-terminated

I have functions like the following:

```
const char* get_message() {
    return "This is a constant message, will NOT change forever!";
};

const char* get_message2() {
    return "message2";
};
```

And I'm planning to use them everywhere my app, even though in different threads.

I'm wondering about the life time of these strings, i.e. whether it's safe to use these `const char*` string out of the function `get_message`.

I guess that a hard coded `const char*` string will be compiled into the codes segment of a app instead of the data segments, so maybe it is safely to use them as above?

Comment: Literal strings like that have a life-time of the whole program. But note that a `const char *` can point to non-literal strings as well, and the life-time of those string depends on what they're pointing to.

Comment: Obligatory nitpick, string literals have type `const char [N]`, not `const char *`.

Comment: I would suggest `auto&` instead of `const char*` to not  needlessly loose type information. It will also make functions requiring arrays of known bound happy - and you can use range-based for loops on the returned C strings if needed. [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/W4no8dvMY)

Comment: I would still return a `static const char[] ret = "message2";`. Afaik it doesnt hurt, makes it more explicit, and saves the next one reading the code from the same doubt

Comment: Simple solution for strings in C++: Use `std::string` for *all* your strings. Then the life-time issue is sidestepped. There are exception (as for any strict rule) where `std::string_view` might be a better choice, but if you only use `std::string` you can't go wrong.

Comment: This is the bad thing with "C" style coding and why C++ has containers (like `std::vector`, `std::string`) and smart pointers like `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr` all these types help with describing lifetime of objects. Your constant object probably is best modeled using a `std::string_view` and a message that can change using `std::string`

Comment: @PepijnKramer Why add complexity when it's not needed? A string literal has static lifetime, which effectively means that it's simply there, always. So why mess with dynamic allocation, be it explicit (smart pointer) or implicit (`std::string`).

Comment: Of course, if you have c++17 or later, it might make sense to return a `std::string_view`. But I'm not sure -- there are just too many interfaces still floating around which require a `char const*`. (All of Posix, for example.)

Comment: Probably opinion based but std::string_view IMO does not add complexity it makes code more consistent because everything is objects then (instead of needing a pointer). And by using string_view you at least communicate that the string cannot be freed

Comment: The formulation is a bit unfortunate in that the last question asks about something that is irrelevant to the rest of the question. Where in the process/binary string literals are stored is completely irrelevant to what their lifetime is and whether they can be safely used during the whole program. Both the code and data segments are allocated for the duration of the whole program. That causes two completely different kinds of answers, both of which answer only either the initial question or the last one.

Comment: Will the message need to be translated in a later version?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer is string literal "message2" will exist in memory
as long as process, but in .*rodata* section (assuming we talk about ELF file).

We return pointer to string constant, but as we will latter see, there is not separate memory defined anywhere which stores this `const char *` pointer
and there is no need to, as address of string is calculated in code and returned using register $**rax** every time function is called.

But lets take a look in the code what happens with **gdb**

[image]

We put breakpoint in our function returning a pointer to constant string, and we see assembly code and process map:

[image]

Code gets this string in following instruction:

```
0x000055555555514a <+8>:    lea    0xeb3(%rip),%rax        # 0x555555556004
```

What this instruction does it calculates address of "message2".
We see here what PIC (position independent code) means.

Address of "message2" string is not hardcoded as absolute,
but is calculated as relative, as hardcoded offset 0xeb3 of next instruction address (0x555555555151 + 0xeb3) and put in register **rax**.

Purpose of relative addressing (current address +/- offset)
means process will always get the right address of "message2",
no matter where in memory it is loaded.

So here we see that `const char *` that you asked actually doesn't exist in memory, because address is calculated "on the fly" and returned using $rax:

We have address in $rax:

```
(gdb) i r $rax
rax   0x555555556004      93824992239620
```

And it holds address of "message2":

```
(gdb) x/s 0x555555556004
0x555555556004: "message2"
```

Now lets see where address **0x555555556004** in process address map
is:

```
0x555555556000     0x555555557000     0x1000     0x2000  r--p   /home/drazen/proba/main
```

So this section is not executable and not writable, just readable and private (r--p) which makes sense as this is not shared library.

When we check with readelf it shows that it is in the .rodata section of ELF file:

```
drazen@HP-ProBook-640G1:~/proba$ readelf  -x .rodata main

Hex dump of section '.rodata':
0x00002000 01000200 6d657373 61676532 00       ....message2.
```

So answer is that this string will not be hardcoded in code segment *.text* of the ELF file but read only data segment *.rodata*, but yes it will exist as long process exists in memory.

And just to add small detail, this constant string will be returned to main() function by reference of course (address), but not on the stack but in register **rax**:

```
(gdb) i r
rax   0x555555556004      93824992239620
rbx   0x0
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Technically you are right. But in the context of the question it doesn't really matter. Also your answer is very platform specific and not necessarily true for all platforms.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code/data.

Comment: You can't judge whether some code is legal from the assembly alone. UB could give you one assembly on one compiler, and break things on another.

Comment: well, question was, was this string hard-coded into code segment, and technically it isnt, because code segment is where instructions are, and this constant string is not coded as a part of assembly instruction, is just plain data so its places in rodata section. I haven't tried this on different platforms, but i am sure it will be placed in rodata as well.

Comment: @DrazenGrasovec It doesn't matter where it is placed. The standard guarantees static lifetime, so the compiler must do something to ensure static lifetime. Different linkers and different architectures have different notions of segments. I've used compilers which placed string literals in the same segment as code, and even ones that placed it in the same segment as other data (and which allowed overwriting it!).

Comment: @DrazenGrasovec Thanks for your answer! It not only give me the answer, but also let me get more knowledge about readonly data segment. In addition I'm just using Linux too.

Comment: I am pretty confident that all compilers which produce ELF executable will place static constants and string literals in .rodata section. But I dont know for Windows and other non Linux/UNIX toolchains. But yes it Is possible I guess to "mix" string literals somewhere into code section.

Comment: @JamesKanze Yeah, that was my first reaction too, but OP actually asked about the section for some unknown reason.

Comment: @DrazenGrasovec: Yes, ELF platforms have always used `.rodata`.  Older linkers (like GNU Binutils until the last few years) used to link that section into the same segment as the `.text` section, so code and read-only data were grouped separately but the boundary between them could be inside a page.  `ld` changed its default linker script to avoid that for reasons like Spectre and ROP gadgets: any bytes that don't need to be in an executable page doesn't go in one, [making tiny executable larger with more padding.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65038281/224132)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat To which the only answer is: it's not specified. Different compilers, or even different versions of the same compiler, might put it is different sections -- for that matter, the section might depend on the compiler options (whether pic is requested or not, for example). About all you can say is that a modern compiler will put it somewhere where it's read-only (but early compilers didn't).

Answer (score 16):

To give an answer from the standard, `"message"` is a string literal, and string literals have static lifetime, which means that the object (the `char const[N]` which contains the characters) has a lifetime for the entire program. (It's a bit more complicated for objects with non-trivial constructors or destructors). So pointers to it will be valid for the lifetime of the program.

Comment: I've edited `char const[]` -> `char const[N]`, since the former is also a valid type (though not used in OP's code), so using it as a shorthand for the latter could be a bit confusing.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, it is safe to do that. Your assumptions are correct.

Comment: It is not quite right, because if you consider code segment is ,text, but this string constant will be compiled into .rodata section of ELF file

Comment: @DrazenGrasovec Yes, and in PE files it will usually be the ``.rdata`` segment. But this is a technical detail that is not really helpful in the context of the question (in my opinion).

Comment: @DrazenGrasovec The standard doesn't speak about code segments in binary files, which is an implementation detail. It does however say that string literals have `static` storage duration and your code is therefore safe, no matter where the actual string literals end up.

Answer (score 7):

> I'm wondering about the life time of these strings, i.e. whether it's safe to use these `const char*` string out of the function `get_message`.

A quick look at the standard then.

> Evaluating a string-literal results in a string literal object with static storage duration, initialized from the given characters as specified above. Whether all string-literals are distinct (that is, are stored in nonoverlapping objects) and whether successive evaluations of a string-literal yield the same or a different object is unspecified. [Note: The effect of attempting to modify a string-literal is undefined. —end note] 
> —-ISO/IEC JTC1 SC22 WG21 N4860 (section 5.13.5 [String literals])

**So yes**. After the function evaluates the string literal and returns a `const char*` to the string literal, the standard assures that this string literal will be given [static storage duration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/static_storage_duration).