# Size of a C executable compiled by gcc

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-optimization

Below is the C program compiled with gcc and sizes of their executables. I also stripped out debug instructions with `-s` flag, but that only freed ~2KB.

Optimization flags do not change the size.

What does compiler generate for that many bytes? Some high level ideas and reference pointers are welcome.

With raw section sizes it's much smaller but the question still holds.

```
> cat test.c
int main() {
    return 1;
}
> gcc test.c
> ll test.c a.out
-rwxrwxr-x 1 atxa atxa 16K Dec 29 04:08 a.out*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 atxa atxa  29 Dec 29 03:15 test.c
> gcc -s test.c
> ll test.c a.out
-rwxrwxr-x 1 atxa atxa 14K Dec 29 04:09 a.out*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 atxa atxa  29 Dec 29 03:15 test.c

> size a.out
   text   data     bss     dec     hex  filename
   1228    544       8    1780     6f4  a.out
```

If the answer is just "runtime", then please provide more details.

Comment: Try something like `objdump -x a.out` for more detail on exactly what is in the file (and where).  Mostly it is (fixed) overhead for dynamic linking with the C library and startup stuff.

Comment: It _is_ "just runtime". The actual compiled code for your `main` _function_ is 6 bytes. When compiled with `-c`, we can do (e.g.) `size ./main.o` and get a text size of 54 bytes. The remaining size is taken up by the code that `gcc` injects to startup/call your `main` (e.g. `crt0.o`)

Comment: If you use `od -x a.out` you'll see that a large chunk of it is empty. I think each section of the file begins at an even multiple of the page size.

Comment: Related: [Minimal executable size now 10x larger after linking than 2 years ago, for tiny programs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65037919) for hand-written asm and linker defaults (aligning segments for 4K page boundaries, and putting the `.rodata` section in its own segment.)  You can disassemble with `objdump -drwC a.out` (and optionally `-Mintel`) to see what got linked in from `crt*.o` files.  `gcc -s -v test.o` will also show the commands it ran, including the paths to some `.o` files.  The choice depends on `-pie` (default) vs. `-no-pie` vs. `-static-pie` or maybe `-static`